# Quick settings got broken after reboot

Tags: gnome-shell-extension, 22.10

I rebooted my PC and quick settings got broken. This could be because of the Quick Settings Tweaker extension. However, disabling it and rebooting didn't solve the issue. I'm using Ubuntu 22.10 and all packages are up to date. What should I do?

Broken quick settings:

[image: Screenshot of broken quick settings]

Enabled extensions:

[image: Enabled extensions]

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the Notification Banner Reloaded extension solved the issue.

Comment: This is not very clear.  could you clarify where the 'Notification Banner Reloaded extension' can be found and how to disable it?

Comment: It's just a regular GNOME extension. I disabled it from [GNOME Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org).